# Share photo on one of my facebook pages

Tags: java, facebook

I created an application that shares a picture to my Facebook wall without any problem, but I did not find a solution for sharing an image on one of my facebook groups.

I use this code right now:

```
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(selectedImage)
            .setCaption("tag")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I use graph api calls instead of using the ShareApi.

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putByteArray("object_attachment", byteArray); // object attachment must be either byteArray
bundle.putString("message","message_to_the_post");

GraphRequest graph =new GraphRequest(pageAccessToken,
    "/<page_id>/photos",//
    bundle,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse)
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }
    });

graph.executeAsync();
```